# Syntax Error in MySQL integrated with Python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am trying to code a program that takes input from the user into a variable n, and creates a table in mySQL based on the input. However, I am facing an unprecedented error that just keeps popping up time and again spontaneously about there being a syntax error. Can anyone please point out the error? Can't seem to find one here.

```
        CREATE TABLE '{}'
        (seat_no numeric(6) primary key, 
         class varchar(1) not null,
         vacancy varchar(1) not null, 
         price numeric(5) not null, 
         occupant_id numeric(6) )
        '''.format(n))
        con1.commit()
```

The error shown is as follows:

```
ERROR: 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '122102
( Seat_No   decimal(6) PRIMARY KEY,
  Class     varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  Va' at line 1
```

I have tried removing the primary key at all, and changing the data types, to no avail.

Comment: If you want to create a table whose name is clear numeric string then you'd quote it properly.

Comment: n is not being input as a numeric string

Comment: @agrim please clarify your question, it cannot be answered as it stands.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show where `n` comes from or what it's supposed to be ("based on the input" does not tell us anything at all), but it looks like you pass a number (`122102`), and your SQL command tries to use it as the name of the table to create. But table names can't be numbers.

You should figure out how you ended up in this situation so you can fix the problem.

Comment: Even when I pass a string in n (say, `J122012`), it shows the same error.

Comment: Why don't you debug your SQL directly against mysql (e.g. open command-line mysql), then you'll know what you need to generate.

Comment: There's no way we could test this for you, your code fragment is far too incomplete; it's not even valid Python statements; and the error message does not show the quotes around the name that your string should have inserted. Please see "how to ask a good question" and edit your answer to provide the additional information. No point in trying to guess what you will not include in your question.